# How can I setup credentials for git push on Teamcity's PowerShell build step?

Tags: git, powershell, teamcity

I have been trying to git push some changes on the local branch of an agent to a remote branch on a PowerShell build step. A post from this link https://teamcity-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206151989-How-to-push-changes-back-to-source-repo-in-git says that I need to store credentials in its Git credential manager.

I have tried to use "git config" to set email password but it still didn't work. I also don't know how to use the command "git credential". My script is below, the build got stuck at the git push line:

```
git config --global user.email %git_username%
git config --global user.password %git_password%
git config --global credential.helper store
git remote add origin2 %client_git_url%
git push origin2 %local_branch%:main
```